# What data type to use for a very large numbers

Tags: vb.net, numeric, biginteger

I'm trying to get a very big number, it doesn't work with usual integer,long...
I've searched it and I found that there is a namespace named `System.Numerics` but when I write:
`Imports System.Numerics` , it doesn't accept.
If I could use that, I'm sure that I could also use:

```
Dim x as new BigInteger(y)
```

What can I do in this situation, are there any other methods?

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.Numerics.dll?

Comment: You can use the Decimal Data Type (Visual Basic). It can hold numbers from `-79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335` through `79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335` if you do not use any decimal places.

Comment: How big is your number?

Comment: Sorry I've been working on something else so I couldn't answer. -@ Mike Cheel I couldn't find the dll file where can I find it, I found one but it didn't work. -@Nizam thanks for your help but my number is bigger. -@Matt Wilko my number changes but I think it'll have 100 digits at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a reference to System.Numerics in the solution explorer

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2442e03e-efad-4dfb-89ce-b19e0247e3bb/systemnumerics